# migrating from GIT to TF without losing authors and timestamps

Tags: git, tfs

We are trying to transfer our Bitbucket repository using this guide here:

[http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/04/02/importing-a-git-repository-into-tfs/\](http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/04/02/importing-a-git-repository-into-tfs/%5C) 
The last time we did this, we lost all information on the original author and timestamp of each commit/changeset. Instead, they were given a new author and timestamp (I was the author because I was doing the transfer and the timestamp was the time and date of the transfer). We were wondering if anyone knows how to avoid this. The link above shows how to use Git-TF to do the transfer. How do we use Git-TF to transfer not only the entire commit/changeset history but the original authors and timestamps of each commit/changeset?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to move to Git on TFS? TFVC is a centralized version control system that behaves differently then Git. BitBucket Git and TFS Git are fully compatible and that migration would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; timestamp and author are fundamental parts of a TFVC commit and can't be "faked".

Answer (score 0):

**Technically**, that is at least possible to keep the original author (I don't remember for the timestamp but I think it's possible). TFS api is able to do it.

[git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) is able to do it also but require 2 things:

- that the user that do the checkins (with `git-tfs rcheckin`) have the right to checkin for other users (that's a setting of TFS)
- that you use an author file that contains the mapping between git users and TFS ones.

**Unfortunately**, git-tfs is not able to migrate the history like you want to do it :(

So, perhaps if you dig in git-tf source code and add this feature...